# Jupyter Lab Dask Extension on AKS: Dask dashboard windows empty

Tags: dask, jupyter-lab, azure-aks

I recently learned to deploy Dask on [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) using helm (for reference my notes are [here](https://sites.google.com/view/raybellwaves/cheat-sheets/azure-vms#h.p_6Mb0lF20RMqI)).

I was able to run code in Jupyter Lab but I couldn't pin the scheduler next to the notebook to see the Dask Dashboard. I'm hoping to make it look cool as in [here](https://youtu.be/we1m4-IsbL8?t=654). Although, I was able to access the dashboard as a different IP address given by the EXTERNAL-IP of the scheduler.

Is there something I am missing for how to get the scheduler to show up in a notebook? I clicked on the dask extension tab and tried to copy in the URL with little success.

When testing locally I was able to get find the dashboard just by clicking the on the magnifying glass (Auto-detect dashboard URL) and it found http://127.0.0.1:8787/

Do I need to get the scheduler on the same IP address as the jupyter notebook?

[image]

Comment: well, you probably need to tell it where to look for scheduler, since on localhost it works because it scans localhost (I would imagine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to successfully navigate to the dashboard in a separate tab then copy that same address into the text field in the dask labextension and things should be ok.